# VMWare resize disk size using vcenter api

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have been trying to solve this for the past week.
I'm using the vcenter API to add a new disk to an existing VM
https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/1cd28284-3b72-4885-9e31-d1c6d9e26686/71ef7304-a6c9-43b3-a3cd-868b2c236c81/doc/operations/com/vmware/vcenter/vm/hardware/disk.create-operation.html

and as able to do it successfully.

But I cannot figure out how to resize an existing VM disk.
https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/1cd28284-3b72-4885-9e31-d1c6d9e26686/71ef7304-a6c9-43b3-a3cd-868b2c236c81/doc/operations/com/vmware/vcenter/vm/hardware/disk.update-operation.html

This disk update operation does not allow to update the "capacity" attribute. So I'm not sure how to resolve this, unless I use an SDK.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% up to speed on the latest version, but there are several things that the REST API cannot do compared to the "old" SDK which is based on SOAP / WSDL.

The documentation on the page also states that the call only: "Updates the configuration of a virtual disk. An update operation can be used to detach the existing VMDK file and attach another VMDK file to the virtual machine." So there's no mention of changing the size (which is pretty lame I have to say...).

So I think unfortunately it seems like you either

1. Wait for a new version and hope this will be included
2. You use the good old SDK